# Have I drawn this Venn diagram correctly?

Tags: logic

Does this look correct?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4jlS.png

I'm trying to find out whether this syllogism is valid (I'm guessing it's not valid)

Many thanks

Comment: What do the shaded areas mean?

Comment: Basically by shading out what I have, what's left is all cacti are plants (the intersection part) - by shading this out, this region does not exist anymore

Comment: And what does the red cross mean? I don't really get how drawing 3 circles proves or disproves your syllogism...

Comment: the red cross means some plants are green- but because there are two regions to pick it goes on the bit where C intersects G

it's using a venn diagram method.. very common

Comment: OK, and how can you conclude anything about your syllogism from this?

Comment: well for the conclusion to be true, we would need an 'x' in C surely? i think the diagram refers to the fact, some cacti may or may not be green (we can't say for sure)

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Yes, you would. But in order to prove that the syllogism is false, you need to *prove* that an $x$ in $C$ may not necesarily exist.

Comment: well we can't say with 100% certainty that some cacti are not green because of where the 'x' is situated, and because of that I would conclude the syllogism is invalid

Comment: That's not a mathematically rigorous proof.

Comment: Why does it need to be a mathematical proof? if what's left on the venn diagram doesnt match with the required conclusion, that should be enough. otherwise whats the point of doing this method lol? (the question specifically asked to use this method)

Comment: I don't know the context in which the question was asked. And my point was not that your proof needs to be "mathematical" (whatever that means), I wanted to say that the proof is not *rigorous.* You say "we can't say with 100% certainty that some cacti are not green". How do you know that? I mean, this statement is true, but you gave no proof of it. Therefore, your proof is not rigorous.

Comment: The syllogism can only be valid if we can say with 100% certainty the conclusion is true. we assume the two statements are true when drawing the venn diagram, then using the diagram, we need to be able to see whether the conclusion is clearly visible to be 100% true. now we can only say its totally true if the x was c and not c and g... but its not. therefore this syllogism cant be valid

Comment: And how do you now that you can only say that? You *still* did not prove that you *cannot* say the conclusion is true.

Comment: the conclusion can only be true if x is c (not g included) no? if this is not the case the syllogism has to be invalid since we assume the first two states are true when drawing the venn diagram

Comment: But what if there is some other $x$ (not the one from the statement "some plants are green") which is not included in $G$?

Comment: The point is that you can prove that your statement is untrue by providing a **model** in which the first two statements are true, but the conclusion is not. That model consists of one plant which is a cactus and is green. Then, the statements above your horizontal line are true, and the one below is not. Therefore, the conclusion is false.

Comment: To narrow it down, consider it like this: the shaded region no longer exists. So the only way to allow the conclusion to be true is to have the x situated in the unshaded region of c and p-> that's the only possible way for the conclusion to be true. since the x is not there, we cannot conclude that the conclusion is true

Comment: "So the only way to allow the conclusion to be true is to have the x situated in the unshaded region of c and p"

True. But the $x$ need not be the $x$ from the statement "some plants are green". There may be more $x$-es, not just the one you drew.

Comment: but since a syllogism consists of only 3 statements, how are we going to get another x?

Comment: You can't. But you need to **prove** that you can't. That's the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: if we consider which regions the x could go in: one of them suggests that some cacti could be green lolz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following argument is invalid:

(P1): All **C**acti are **P**lants. (P2): Some **P**lants are **G**reen. Conclusion: Some **C**acti are not **G**reen.

It's just that the non-Green plants needn't have any Cacti among them. The Venn diagram below illustrates that. Note that the diagram satisfies both (P1) and (P2), as required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not satisfying the first condition because the way you drew it says that not all C are P.

Comment: No it doesnt? i shaded out the region that would say 'not all c are p' lol (this is from what I've learnt anyway..)

Comment: It is not clear from the diagram that you have shaded out what is not relevant.

Comment: @prime4567 everywhere I've read seems to be using this rule as standard practice

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I got it right:

You draw three circles that show all possibilities of things being cacti, plants and green.

You shade areas that you know are empty (from premises) and you mark with red x an area known to be not empty (since some plants are green).

Now, all unshaded and separated areas may have something in them or they may be empty. We just do not know.

Conclusion declares that some cacti are not green. This area in our Venn diagram is unshaded. It may have something in it or it may be empty. Therefore we can not make such conclusion.

If we accept silent premise that there are some cacti (danger!) then we have also look if cacti$\times$not green is only area where cacti may be. If so, our conclusion should be true (given silent premise). But from our Venn diagram we see that there is other area, where cacti can be, namely cacti$\times$green. So we can not make that conclusion and syllogism is false.

And about question: diagram is correct given you read it correctly.

Comment: this is my exact same line of thinking

Comment: funnily enough its possible that some cacti are green (since we;re not sure which region the x could go in :p)

Answer (score -2):

Statement 1: All cacti are plants implies that the cacti circle is 'in' the plant circle.
Statement 2: Some plants are green implies that there exist plants which are green. This may include the possibility of all plants turning green but excluding the possibility of 'not even one' plant which is not green. So, plant circle interaction with the green circle is 'non-zero'.
Statement 3: Some cacti are not green. You can never conclude this statement from the above two because there is no imformation of interaction of the cacti circle with the green circle.